# Javascript Replace function not working with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I have following string:

```
@[A:B:C].[X:Y:Z].[P:Q:R] 1.C.3.s @[1:2:3].[2:0:0].[5dsh:cxcv:wew]
```

I want to extract sub-strings from these that are in following format:

```
@[anything here].[anything here].[anything here]
```

In above case the output sub-strings should be:

```
@[A:B:C].[X:Y:Z].[P:Q:R]
@[1:2:3].[2:0:0].[5dsh:cxcv:wew]
```

I have this regular expression that matches these sub-strings:

```
(@\w+|@(?:\[[^\]]+\]\.?)+)
```

To test this regular expression I am replacing these sub-strings with `$` in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vfe50z0o/

There is no problem with the regular expression as it is working in this Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/aH9nK5/1

But on JSFiddle it's not working.

This is JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var re = /(@\w+|@(?:\[[^\]]+\]\.?)+)/; 
    var str = 'wewe@[s].[s].[s]xvcv';
    var subst = '$';
    var result = str.replace(re, subst);
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work because you've put your function in a "load" handler, and therefore it isn't global so the event handler fails. Change the fiddle setting to "nowrap - in body" and your fiddle works fine.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks that solved the problem. Add it as answer I will mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with such format strings the following regex can does the job :

```
(@?\[[^[]*\]\.?){3}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP7qZ6/1)

If the number of brackets can be more or less than 3 you can use `+` :

```
(@?\[[^[]*\]\.?)+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get your matches:

```
var re = /(@\w*(?:\[[^\]]+\]\.?)+)/g; 
var str = '@[A:B:C].[X:Y:Z].[P:Q:R] 1.C.3.s @[1:2:3].[2:0:0].[5dsh:cxcv:wew]';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
@[A:B:C].[X:Y:Z].[P:Q:R]
@[1:2:3].[2:0:0].[5dsh:cxcv:wew]
```